# Is it possible to change this code so that the generic method parameters can be inferred?

Tags: c#, generics

I have written a simple mediator for my WPF application (which is a derivative of the code found [here](http://brentedwards.net/2010/04/13/roll-your-own-simple-message-bus-event-aggregator/)).

```
public class Messenger
{
    private IDictionary<Type, IList<MessageObserver>> observers;

    public Messenger()
    {
        observers = new Dictionary<Type, IList<MessageObserver>>();
    }

    public IDisposeObserver AddObserver<TMessageType>(Action<TMessageType> handler) 
        where TMessageType : Message { }

    protected abstract void RemoveObserver<TMessageType>(Action<TMessageType> handler) 
        where TMessageType : Message { }

    public abstract void PostMessage<TMessageType>(TMessageType message) 
        where TMessageType : Message { }
}
```

`Message` is just an empty class that provides a base class for all messages that are posted via the `Messenger`. The idea is you would derive from this class to create a specific message class with relevant data (a bit like `EventArgs`).

Where my implementation differs is in the way I want to remove observers. I want to be able to specify when they should be removed in a declarative way, along the lines of:

```
MessengerInstance.AddObserver<LoginMessage>(HandleLogin)
    .RemoveObserverWhen(message => message.LoginResult == LoginResult.Successful);
```

The `RemoveObserverWhen` method takes a `Predicate<T>` where `T` should be the message type specified in the `AddObserver` method.

The idea here is you can specify the logic that removes the observer in the same place as registering the observer itself. The Messenger class will then check the predicate after the message handler has been run and remove both the message handler and the removal handler if the predicate evaluates to true.

Each message handler can have any number of removal handlers so I have packaged this up in a class called `MessageObserver`.

```
public class MessageObserver : IDisposeObserver
{
    private IList<object> disposalHandlers;

    public MessageObserver(object observer)
    {
        Observer = observer;
        disposalHandlers = new List<object>();
    }

    public object Observer { get; private set; }

    public IList<object> DisposalHandlers
    {
        get { return disposalHandlers; }
    }

    public IDisposeObserver RemoveObserverWhen<T>(Predicate<T> predicate) 
        where T : Message
    {
        disposalHandlers.Add(predicate);
        return this;
    }
}
```

The `MessageObserver` implements `IDisposeObserver` which provides the `RemoveObserverWhen` method.

```
public interface IDisposeObserver
{
    IDisposeObserver RemoveObserverWhen<T>(Predicate<T> predicate) 
        where T : Message;
}
```

The idea here is that an `IDisposeObserver` instance can be returned so that methods can be chained.

All this works and I have the following code in my viewModel:

```
MessengerInstance.AddObserver<LoginMessage>(HandleLogin)
    .RemoveObserverWhen<LoginMessage>(message => message.LoginResult == LoginResult.Successful)
    .RemoveObserverWhen<LoginMessage>(SecondDisposalHandler);
```

The problem I have is that this only works if I specify the generic parameter (`LoginMessage` in this case) when calling the `RemoveObserver` method. I would like to be able to call the methods in the way described at the beginning of the post.

I think I need to somehow return a generic `IDisposeObserver` but if I make this change then the `MessageObserver` has to be made generic and then I cannot specify the constraints as the `Messenger` class is non generic.

So my question is, **Can my code be updated so that I do not have to specify the message type when calling the `RemoveObserverWhen` method or do I have to live with my current solution?**

Note: I am aware that there are other implementations of this available but I am doing this to help my understanding of object oriented design principles and generics in c# so please do not point me in the direction of other implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think I need to somehow return a generic IDisposeObserver but if I make this change then the MessageObserver has to be made generic and then I cannot specify the constraints as the Messenger class is non generic.

You probably want to have a non-generic `MessageObserver` base class which contains all the type-neutral parts, and then a generic one which implements a generic `IDisposeObserver<T>`. You can then change `AddObserver` to return the generic `IDisposeObserver<T>`, but keep the dictionary within `Messenger` as `IDictionary<Type, IList<MessageObserver>>`. So just to be clear, you'd have:

```
public interface IDisposeObserver<T>
{
    IDisposeObserver<T> RemoveObserverWhen(Predicate<T> predicate) 
        where T : Message;
}

public abstract class MessageObserver { ... }

public class MessageObserver<T> : MessageObserver, IDisposeObserver<T> { ... }
```

The problem then comes when you have to *execute* the `IDiposeObserver<T>.RemoveObserverWhen` method - you may well need to just cast each item within the dictionary's list to `IObserver<T>`. You'd know the `T` at that point, and you'd know that you'd populated the list appropriately.

Of course, if that's the *only* thing you're going to do with the observers, you could just keep an `IDictionary<Type, IList<object>>` instead, and not bother having the two different `MessageObserver` classes. It really depends on whether you get any value out of the non-generic one.